# GitPython and SSH Keys?

Tags: python, git, ssh-keys, gitpython

How can I use GitPython along with specific SSH Keys?

The documentation isn't very thorough on that subject. The only thing I've tried so far is `Repo(path)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please note that all of the following will only work in GitPython v0.3.6 or newer.

You can use the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to provide an executable to git which will call `ssh` in its place. That way, you can use any kind of ssh key whenever git tries to connect.

This works either per call using a [context manager](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html#git.cmd.Git.custom_environment) ...

```
ssh_executable = os.path.join(rw_dir, 'my_ssh_executable.sh')
with repo.git.custom_environment(GIT_SSH=ssh_executable):
    repo.remotes.origin.fetch()
```

... or more persistently using the [`set_environment(...)`](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.6/reference.html#git.cmd.Git.update_environment) method of the `Git` object of your repository:

```
old_env = repo.git.update_environment(GIT_SSH=ssh_executable)
# If needed, restore the old environment later
repo.git.update_environment(**old_env)
```

As you can set any amount of environment variables, you can use some to pass information along to your ssh-script to help it pick the desired ssh key for you.

More information about the becoming of this feature (new in GitPython v0.3.6) you will find [in the respective issue](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/234).

Comment: Have to admit that I'm struggling with this as well. I'd really rather not write a custom SSH script. Is there any way to just identify the key to use? I'm new-ish to Python and the tutorial/API just aren't quite getting me where I need to be to get this working. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out, starting with git 2.3, this is pretty much built-in. Using the new GIT_SSH_COMMAND, you can specify the ssh -i ... command now directly, rather than relying on an external script.

Comment: Thanks. The following isn't working for me. What am I missing (formatting sucks in comments, but hopefully you get the idea)? `with git_project.git.custom_environment(GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@bitbucket.org'): git_project.remotes.origin.push(git_project.heads.master)`. If I add the `-T` option and execute from the command line, I logged in as expected. Formatting issue in my Python code?

Comment: Note that I added the `git@bitbucket.org` after an attempt without it also failed. Desperation trial & error, I guess. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I lack personal experience with these environment variables. Maybe it's worth adding a new question that is specific to your particular problem.

Comment: You also shouldn't have to supply the hostname, so try omitting the `git@bitbucket.org`.

Comment: I don't understand what to do here... where do I put the path to my ssh key?

Answer (score 18):

Following worked for me on gitpython==2.1.1

```
import os
from git import Repo
from git import Git

git_ssh_identity_file = os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_rsa')
git_ssh_cmd = 'ssh -i %s' % git_ssh_identity_file

with Git().custom_environment(GIT_SSH_COMMAND=git_ssh_cmd):
     Repo.clone_from('git@....', '/path', branch='my-branch')
```

Comment: What is the variable 'git' in this example?

Comment: You mean git@? That is the repo url, for example git@github.com:django/django.git

Comment: The line ``with git.custom_environment(GIT_SSH_COMMAND=git_ssh_cmd):`` ... what is **git** ?  There is no variable or import that defines git in your code snippet.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I don't know but I think its having issue with adding the private key in the "os.path.expanduser(...)" step.  Is there anyway i can verify the add is successful?

Comment: This doesn't work in the case of `clone_from`. Check my answer below for a working version.

Comment: Source in GitPython docs. [Handling Remotes](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#handling-remotes). At least as at GitPython==3.0.2

Comment: https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/339. This the GIT_SSH_COMMAND configt won't work for the clone_from() function.

Comment: @ozn `os.path.expanduser(...)` returns a filename, a string. `add` - no, GitPython just passed it as argument to git executable.

Comment: `clone_from` now has the keyword `env` to pass the environment: Repo.clone_from(url, dst_path, branch=branch, env=dict(GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh_cmd))

Answer (score 16):

I'm on GitPython==3.0.5 and the below worked for me.

```
from git import Repo
from git import Git    
git_ssh_identity_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'ssh_key.key')
git_ssh_cmd = 'ssh -i %s' % git_ssh_identity_file
Repo.clone_from(repo_url, os.path.join(os.getcwd(), repo_name),env=dict(GIT_SSH_COMMAND=git_ssh_cmd))
```

Using repo.git.custom_environment to set the GIT_SSH_COMMAND won't work for the clone_from function. Reference: https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/339

Answer (score 10):

In case of a `clone_from` in GitPython, the answer by Vijay doesn't work. It sets the git ssh command in a new `Git()` instance but then instantiates a separate `Repo` call. What does work is using the `env` argument of `clone_from`, as I learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802505/4126114):

```
Repo.clone_from(url, repo_dir, env={"GIT_SSH_COMMAND": 'ssh -i /PATH/TO/KEY'})
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work for me.
Any updates on this?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 4):

I've found this to make things a bit more like the way git works in the shell by itself.

```
import os
from git import Git, Repo

global_git = Git()
global_git.update_environment(
    **{ k: os.environ[k] for k in os.environ if k.startswith('SSH') }
)
```

It basically is copying the SSH environment variables to GitPython's "shadow" environment. It then uses the common SSH-AGENT authentication mechanisms so you don't have to worry about specifying exactly which key it is.

For a quicker alternative which carries probably a lot of cruft with it, but it works too:

```
import os
from git import Git

global_git = Git()
global_git.update_environment(**os.environ)
```

That mirrors your entire environment, more like the way a subshell works in bash.

Either way, any future call to create a repo or clone picks up the 'adjusted' environment and does the standard git authentication.

No shim scripts necessary.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows be careful where you place the quotes. Say you have

```
git.Repo.clone_from(bb_url, working_dir, env={"GIT_SSH_COMMAND": git_ssh_cmd})
```

then this works:

```
git_ssh_cmd = f'ssh -p 6022 -i "C:\Users\mwb\.ssh\id_rsa_mock"'
```

but this does not:

```
git_ssh_cmd = f'ssh -p 6022 -i C:\Users\mwb\.ssh\id_rsa_mock'
```

Reason:

https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3131

https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1895

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to clone gitlab repository using GitPython

1. Create SSH key in [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html)
2. Run the following script after adding necessary details

   ```py
   from git import Repo
   Repo.clone_from("gitlab_ssh_url", 
                   "path_where_you_want_to_clone_repo", 
                   env={"GIT_SSH_COMMAND": 'ssh -i path_to_ssh_private_key'})

   """
   Example
   Repo.clone_from("git@gitlab.com:some_group/some_repo.git", 
                   "empty_dir/some_repo", 
                   env={"GIT_SSH_COMMAND": 'ssh -i /home/some_user/.ssh/id_rsa'})
   """
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the latest documentation says:

```
ssh_cmd = 'ssh -i id_deployment_key'
with repo.git.custom_environment(GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh_cmd):
    repo.remotes.origin.fetch()
```

From: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#handling-remotes