# How to use remote path for python git.Repo()?

Tags: python, ssh, gitpython

For initialize repo i use

```
repo = git.Repo(path)
```

Is it possible to use remote path like this `user@host:/path/to/repo`?
Thx for comments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28292493/11082684