# Automated git pull from local Gitlab repository using gitpython requires git@gitlab.our.gitlab.url password

Tags: python, git, gitlab, gitpython

We have a locally hosted Gitlab repository which I am trying to automate pushing and pulling with gitpython over ssh with the following script:

```
LOCAL_REPO_PATH = "/path/to/repository"

repo = Repo(LOCAL_REPO_PATH)

origin = repo.remotes[0]
origin.pull()

# Do some automated changes

index = repo.index

index.add(["*"])
index.commit("Removed/Added stuff")

author = Actor("Script","it@place.com)
committer = Actor("Script","it@place.com)

origin.push()
```

The config of the repo is

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@gitlab.<repo url>:<owner username>/<repository name>.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Whenever I try to run it, it reaches origin.pull() and stops execution to ask for git@gitlab.place.com in the following format:

```
Password: 
Password: 
Password: 
git@gitlab.<url>'s password: 
git@gitlab.<url>'s password:
git@gitlab.<url>'s password:
```

After incorrectly entering a password 6 times, it throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "git-test.py", line 15, in <module>
    origin.pull()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/git/remote.py", line 910, in pull
    res = self._get_fetch_info_from_stderr(proc, progress,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/git/remote.py", line 750, in _get_fetch_info_from_stderr
    proc.wait(stderr=stderr_text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/git/cmd.py", line 502, in wait
    raise GitCommandError(remove_password_if_present(self.args), status, errstr)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
  cmdline: git pull -v origin
  stderr: 'fatal: Could not read from remote repository.'
```

Is there any way to be able to automate this without having the password for the git user?

**Edit 1**

I have asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73284447/git-push-pull-over-ssh-to-locally-hosted-gitlab-as-root-requires-gitgitlab-pass), as I have closer narrowed down what the issue is.

Comment: The `git@gitlab.<repo url>:<owner username>/<repository name>.git` URL syntax, to Git, means the same as using `ssh://git@gitlab.<repo url>/<owner username>/<repository name>.git`, so Git will pass the entire `git@gitlab.<repo url>` string to ssh. What *ssh* does with that is up to ssh, so see the ssh documentation. None of the rest is up to Python *or* Git *or* GitLab, it's all up to ssh.

Comment: In general, using ssh here is the right thing, but you *must then set up a machine user for ssh access* (a deployment user or similar, not sure what GitLab call this), then *ensure that the user that runs the automated deployment scripts has password-free access to the deployment keys*.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not actually with GitPython, it is with the .git folder. I attempted to do a `git pull` from the command line, and it gave this error

`error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied`

Consulting this link: [Trying to git pull with error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195814/trying-to-git-pull-with-error-cannot-open-git-fetch-head-permission-denied?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top), I ran `chown myuser:mygroup -R .git`, allowing me to `git pull` with no errors. This fixes the issue above while running the script. Apparently I had messed with the permissions and forgot about it.

I'm not sure why this would prompt me to ssh into git@gitlab, but the issue is now resolved

**Edit 1**:

I've done some experimentation, and running git fetch in `sudo` mode requires the git@gitlab user to execute. I'm working on a way of lowering the privileges for the one command

Since `git pull` is actually a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`, the FETCH_HEAD file is created with the permissions of whoever ran the `git fetch`. I'm assuming that since the script must be run as sudo, the internal `git fetch` is also ran as sudo.

Comment: Good catch. Upvoted. Check what kind of remote URL you are using with `git remote -v`.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [GitPython and SSH Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72553300/6309), you would need to start with a (`gitpython`) clone referencing the path to the private key, whose public key must be registered to the GitLab user account SSH keys settings page.

```py
from git import Repo
Repo.clone_from("gitlab_ssh_url", 
                "path_where_you_want_to_clone_repo", 
                env={"GIT_SSH_COMMAND": 'ssh -i path_to_ssh_private_key'})
```

That way, GitLab will authenticate the actual user trying to clone said repository, and will determine if said user has the right to access the repository they want to clone.